# How can I send data or file from Linux to Linux machines?

Tags: linux, networking, file-transfer

This question is very weird (I'm very beginner). I want send data from Linux to Linux. For example, I have Linux server (RPI3, called 'a'), and another server called 'b'. So I want data(format : python, c, jpg, txt, ...etc) from 'a' to 'b'

What are methods do I use? Here is what I know.

1. using socket
2. using MQTT

I want know above 2 methods are available??

And another methods!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send files from a to b, you can use scp protocol. a and b have to be in the same network.
 `scp sourcedirectory/image.jpg username@IPaddressOfTheDestination:targetdirectory/`

There are obviously another way to send file like the protocol ftp.

Comment: if using scp, Can I check on window?? I mean check on my window computer through throught internet

Answer (score 0):

The other method that you could take is to use the scp command. For example, if you want to transfer the file from server A to B you could use the command scp file.txt username@123.456.789.000: or scp file.txt username@servername: while logged-in inside the server A.

The default destination path of the file will be that home directory of the username. If you wanted the file to be copied other than this, you could append the absolute path of the directory after the : in the above scp command.

If you wanted to copy multiple files, just place the files first in a directory. After that, you could append the -r flag on the above scp command right before the scp command following the directory name. For example, scp -r directory username@123.456.789.000:

There are also other applications that would achieve the same goals(e.g WinSCP or Filezilla) and plenty tutorials available online. Most common cases of using this application is when the user wanted to transfer files from their local machine to the servers.